# How to do Outgoing SMS interception using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I tried many ways to get Notification for Outgoing SMS, but failed. I tried many ways to Block `/get` notifications for Outgoing SMS but failed always. In case of Incoming SMS I got all controls like reading incoming SMS and launching new activity and Blocking incoming SMS to enter inbox and storing it in text file. But same things I could not do without using SMS.

Can anyone please tell me that can I block Outgoing SMS by using Android NDK and how?

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please tell me that can I block Outgoing SMS by using Android NDK

This is not possible. You cannot block outgoing SMSes except via firmware modifications.

Comment: Thanks , But please can you make me sure that its not possible via ndk. I tried all the ways on our development plateform. My last hope is NDK.

Comment: @Sid: There is nothing that you can do with the NDK either.

Answer (score 0):

There is something you can do within the sdk.

Adding this to your activity in the Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
</intent-filter>
```

And consume the intent call in your Activity.

On most devices you will get a popup if you are sending a sms.

Select your app and mark as "do not ask again".

Now your app will consume all sms.

Comment: This only works for applications using `ACTION_SENDTO`, and many SMS-sending applications will use `SmsManager` directly.

Comment: Hi ben, Thanks for answering. But i have used the same procedure but it didn't worked for Samsung galaxy s and Dell handset(dont remember model). Can you please elaborate this procedure more..